# Cookie-policy link in popup shows raw Markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, cookies

Below, the link to the Cookie Policy page on the new customization popup is just raw Markdown:

[image]

Can we fix that?

Comment: It was working a while ago, now it's not... network-wide.

Comment: Also reported on MSO: [Should the cookie warning be updated to include a clickable link?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406338/4642212).

Comment: Maybe related, maybe not: SO refuses to accept my acceptance. The popup pops up again and again. Edit: hmm, after enabling cookielaw.org in NoScript and using "customize settings", it finally seems to have taken, even though I did not actually customize anything. Let's see if it stays taken...

Comment: @torek Is it possible that you're seeing it on different domains? We have... at least five. We don't have a way yet for it to set these settings on a network-wide basis (though that's being planned) so you'll need to set them per domain. If you were seeing it more than that, we'd certainly be interested in hearing about that.

Comment: @Catija: that was happening too (maybe still is, I have not hit all SO domains) but enabling individual settings and then accepting everything did the trick - it's not happening over and over again now.

Comment: Can we consider removing these altogether? This is very buggy and pop up on any new tab even after pressing `Accept all Cookies`. Extremely annoying. Clicking `Customize settings` does nothing for me for some reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed - thanks for the report!

Thanks to Nick Craver and m0sa for handling it!

[image: Screenshot of the new cookie banner with the markdown fixed]